# APACHE - Redirect domain to subfolder to VirtualHost

Tags: redirect, apache-2.4, 301-redirect

i need redirect to a subfolder, when i go to domain.com, redirect to domain.com/foo. In this time i have a simply apache configuration with `Alias /foo /var/www/foo`. I suppose need create a VirtualHost and i have make this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/foo/
</VirtualHost>
```

But i have `too many redirect` error.
I have tried to comment `Alias /foo /var/www/foo` and add :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com/foo
        <Directory /var/www/foo/>
        Options  FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But i have same error, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you are wanting to redirect so I can better help? Are you looking to have sites on both domain.com/ and domain.com/foo?
If not, I would suggest just changing your entry for ServerName to domain.com and leaving your directory /var/www/foo. You also have the option of doing your redirect in the index.html file within domain.com root directory.

Comment: Is the same site, only a document root, when i go to domain.com i need redirect to domain.com/foo

Comment: Why not do the redirect with an entry in the index file as such and leave your apache config as pointing to actual root as you want? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page I say this because you seem to wish to retain the document root where it is but never see its contents because of the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to map a virtual host to the directory above */foo* (consider Jason's comment), use something like:

```
<LocationMatch "^/$">
    Redirect permanent "/" "/foo/"
</LocationMatch>
```

This way you will limit redirect to domain root and prevent current redirect loop - all `Redirect` stanzas are applied for locations **beginning with** the 3rd argument, */foo* including, so you also get redirected from */foo* to */foo*.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason mentioned works for me.

very simple, at apache2/htdocs/

create a index.html file, with below content.

http://localhost  will go index.html first, then redirect to /glassgov1/ subfolder.

```
<html>

<head>

  <!-- redirect default (index.html) page to another page or subfolder -->
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost:10/glassgov1" />
</head>

    <body>

        <h1>It works!</h1>

    </body>

</html>
```

[Redirect from a HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-a-html-page)